# What does //g mean?

Tags: bash, sed

I am looking over a bash file and I don't know what the following lines do:

```
sed s/
//g < setenv.sh > setenv.sh2
```

When running the script, I always get an error on line 2:

```
//g: No such file or directory
```

So what it his trying to do here ?

Comment: probably they were intended to be on same line. Try after joining the lines.

Comment: like this: sed s/ //g < setenv.sh > setenv.sh2 ?

Comment: It looks more like an attempt to embed a newline into a `sed` command.

Comment: Check out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like that's a broken attempt to remove newlines from a file.

```
sed s/<enter|return>//g
```

Of course, it won't work – sed is newline aware. Just joining the lines probably won't do what you want either, unless there's an invisible character between the first slash and the line break. Otherwise you'd end up with

```
sed s///g
```

What you should do instead is identify which character (newline, carriage return, both?) you want, and use `tr -d`

```
tr -d $'\n' < file > file.nonewlines
tr -d $'\r' < file > file.nocarriagereturns
tr -d $'\r\n' < file > file.nocrlfs
```

Comment: so should I use tr instead of sed ?

Comment: @vBx yes, if you're removing newlines.

Answer (score 0):

missing quote or double quote around the action and an escape of the new line also this is certainly part of a bigger script where working buffer could have more than 1 line in it. It is maybe coming from a print copy of a script

```
sed '#other action before this like H or N
s/\
//g' < setenv.sh > setenv.sh2
```

for the `g` it mean *every occurence of the substitution* (s///) but error is coming from the wrong first pattern (escaped enter)

Answer (score 0):

The /g flag cause not only the first occurence in each line to be replaced but all.

```
echo "ggg" | sed -e 's/g/j/' 
# jgg
echo "ggg" | sed -e 's/g/j/g'
# jjj
```